# Find if field is used in a report

Tags: reporting, custom-field, fields

One of the SFDC Admins asked if there is a way I can find out if certain fields are used in any reports/code.  I have the code portion covered but I can't figure out how to find if the fields are used in any reports.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use Visual Studio Code. Download your entire code base and use Visual Studio Code's search function to search all Classes, triggers, and such. Reports and analytic snapshots are accessible this way as well. If your org is small, you should be able to download everything, including objects and custom fields (as any given field can be used in another formula field). If your org is large, you may have to chunk it out into different projects.

Comment: Now this can be achieved with "Where is this Used" and doesn't require such heavy-lifting.

Answer (score 1):

> [This is available Out of the box after **Spring'20**](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZowUAF/show-all-reports-that-use-a-specific-field)

On a custom field’s detail page, click **Where is this used?** to see where a field is used and where changes to the field appear.

This provides us with references if the field is used in reports, report types, and even in any Wave/Einstein Analytics Dataflows.

[image: Custom Field Details]